# vue.js: Filtering not working as I expect

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am using this code to filter OUT any parts with categories OTHER than '1', '2', or '3' but the displayed list isn't filtering out cats like 'LG' and 'NHA'. I am using filter incorrectly?

```
return this.components.filter((c) => {
    if (c.cat in ['1', '2', '3']) {
        return c;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter`'s callback function expects a bool return value. You can use `includes` to determine whether an array includes a certain element.

If you want to filter `components` to only include the elements *other* than 1,2 and 3, you can use `!` to negate the `includes` result.

```js
let components = [{cat: '1'}, {cat: '2'}, {cat: '3'}, {cat: '4'},{cat: '5'}];
let result = components.filter((c) => {
  return !['1', '2', '3'].includes(c.cat);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) doesn't check to see if a value is in an array; it checks to see if a *property name* is present in an object (or its prototypes).

To find out if a value is in an array, you can use the modern [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (which can be polyfilled on older browsers) method, or the older [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
if (['1', '2', '3'].includes(c.cat)) {
```

or

```
if (['1', '2', '3'].indexOf(c.cat) != -1) {
```

For more complex checks, you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which lets you use a callback to check if something matches rather than just doing a value match.